# How to design a database schema in Laravel with an Entity having more than two attributes?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

For using Eloquent in Laravel, I wish to design a database schema where a **PAPER** can have different **FORMAT**, **THICKNESS** and **COLOR** as attributes.

[image: image here]

E.g. a paper can be of size A4, thickness 80gm/m², and color white.
Or, a paper can be of size A3, thickness 160gm/m², and color green. And so on...

How do you people suggest me to design tables? As I've done, a single pivot table with `paper_id`, `format_id`, `thickness_id`, and `color_id` all together? Or a different approach would be better?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is this a fixed set of attributes?

Comment: What you did is perfectly fine. however if you want to decrease the number of tables, you could use enum as well. for example. paper is white or yellowish. it's not black it's not an infinite range. in my opinion for color and size you could use enum.

Comment: Why not having these fields in the Paper table itself?

Comment: @lagbox - Yea, I think these are all attributes that we need at the moment.

Comment: @amirkamizi - Thank you. I learnt about 'enum' just today after your reply :) But I think we will need a lot more colours than just white and yellowish. So, separate seems essential to me.If this table that I created is fine, how do we declare relationships in Laravel? Which of these is a correct approach? 

1. PAPER hasMany FORMAT (no relationship with pivot table)

OR

2. PAPER hasMany PAPERENTRY and FORMAT hasMany PAPERENTRY (including pivot table)

Comment: your structure seems fine. but if it were me, I would merge paper and property together. a simple example would be like this:
TableName: Papers
Columns: id, name, format_id, color_id, weight_it etc.
then regarding the relationships:
Paper has one format, paper has one color, paper has one weight.
format belongs to many papers, color belongs to many papers, weight belongs to many papers.
this way you wouldn't need pivot tables. and you would avoid repetition. 
of course there is not just ONE CORRECT WAY. you could do the way you are more comfortable and it still matches the standards.

Comment: Perfect @amirkamizi. Thanks a lot. Your this last comment really helped me understand the way to organize the DB tables.